Intra prediction for edge boundary block
What would be the values of (A, B, C, D, M, I, J, K, L) for the top left-upper block (edge block) in H.264/AVC intra-prediction?
image 1: Intra block layout

The second picture shows that, in this example, the values of (A, B, C, D, M, I, J, K, L) for the first edge block are assigned 128.
image 2: Example of 128 assignment



I guess your book tries to tell you, that for the first top-left edge block of an image the MABCDEFGHIJKL-samples are simply set to 128 in order to derive the intra prediction-samples. If this doesn't answer your question or you think it is wrong, please read [ask] and add more details!

I am curious about what MABCDEFGHIJKL values are set to in an actual codec (the second picture is just one of the samples provided for understanding).

If there are no neighboring samples to the left or top of a macroblock then the specification suggests to use Intra_4x4_DC prediction mode (mode 2) with constant value:
pred4x4L[ x, y ] = ( 1 << ( BitDepthY − 1 ) ) 

For bit depth 8 this derives to 128.
See Recommendation ITU-T H.264 (V15) (08/2024) chapter 8.3 and specifically formula (8-51).
